# Counting combinations ( help)

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

can you help me with this problem:

This problem concerns lists made from the letters A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J.

(a) How many length-5 lists can be made from these letters if repetition is not
allowed and the list must begin with a vowel?

(b) How many length-5 lists can be made from these letters if repetition is not
allowed and the list must begin and end with a vowel?

(c) How many length-5 lists can be made from these letters if repetition is not
allowed and the list must contain exactly one A?

for a) I said :
3*9*8*7*6

for b) 
I did
3*8*7*6*2

for c) I did
5*(9*8*7*6*1)

I am not sure of a or b

Help is appreciated!

Comment: (a),(b) and (c) look right to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  That looks right.

> (a) How many length-5 lists can be made from these letters if repetition is not allowed and the list must begin with a vowel?

Select one of three vowels for first place, then select and arrange four of nine remaining letters for the others.  $${^{3}\mathrm P_{1}}\;{^{9}\mathrm P_{4}} = 3\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6$$

> (b) How many length-5 lists can be made from these letters if repetition is not allowed and the list must begin and end with a vowel?

Select and arrange two of three vowels for first and last place, then do so for three of eight letters in the middle three places. $${^{3}\mathrm P_{2}}\,{^{8}\mathrm P_{3}} = 3\cdot 2\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6$$

> (c) How many length-5 lists can be made from these letters if repetition is not allowed and the list must contain exactly one A?

Select a place to contain the `A`, then select and permute four of nine letters.  $${^{5}\mathrm C_{1}} \;{^{9}\mathrm P_{4}} = 5\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6$$